# rendering specific layout rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to render a specific layout when the form is NOT properly filled:

Inside my views/layouts I've:

- application.html.erb
- empty.html.erb

My controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
    render layout: "empty" # I wan to re-use this layout is the user is not been saved
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to sign_in_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit!
  end
end
```

The thing is that it works it re-renders the new-action when it's not true BUT it uses Application-default layout and NOT the other layout-file called: **empty.html.erb**

According to  [Rails guide lines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) it should work...but not for me :(

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `def create` method, the `render :new` is rendering the new.html.erb view using the default layout. You can try

```
 render layout: "empty", template: "users/new"
```

`render` merely "paints" the page according to the layout and template given to it.

`redirect_to "new"` will send a request for the `new` action.

Comment: Hi there! just one more question: Why did it work in the first call (inside the new-action=> render layout: "empty") and then in the create-action is requiring more method (template: template: "users/new" ). It's not very clear when I look at the wiki (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for RoR.

Comment: There wasnt a "second" call to new. When you `render :new`, it doesn't call to the `new` action, it merely uses the renders (or draws) the `new.html.erb` and sends the resulting page to the browser.

Comment: "it merely uses the renders (or draws) the new.html.erb" but using application-layout as a default right?

Comment: Yes. `render :new` renders new.html.erb using the default view/layouts/application.html.erb. Note that the `new` action is not called. If you want the `new` action, use `redirect_to "new"`.

Comment: I'm going your first suggestion " render layout: "empty", template: "users/new" ". If I use " redirect_to 'new' " I can't display the validation errors made by the user. It'll reload a new clean template :) thanks!